# Install Windows 8 on Windows 7 OEM laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, oem

I have got a SAMSUNG laptop contains Windows 7 OEM. I have got Windows 8 DVD and would like to know if I can do fresh/clean install of Windows 8 on my laptop ? That way Windows 7 will be completely gone.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what type of license you have.  If its an Windows 8 Upgrade license you have to leave the Windows 7 license on your computer and do a clean installation that way.  If its a System Builder license you can boot to the media and install Winodws 8 that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as the laptop has a DVD drive and the nessarry hardware?

Windows 8 Hardware requirements:
1 GHz processor or faster with support for PAE, NX, and SSE2
2 GB RAM / 20 GB available hard disk space
1366 × 768 screen resolution
DirectX 9 graphics processor with WDDM driver
To use touch, you need a PC that supports multitouch

If it meets these then you can simply nuke the drive and re-install

(In case you don't know what i mean by "nuke the drive" i mean wipe it)

Comment: why the need of a dvd drive? one can use a flash drive for this.